# Forward mail to mailbox in addition to piping

Tags: postfix, smtp, pipe

I've set up postfix to pipe emails through `rdm-mailhandler.rb` (redmine), but I'd also like the emails to be delivered to the mailbox.

transport:

`support@myhost.com redmine`

master.cf:

```
redmine   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe user=mongrel argv=/opt/redmine-1.2.2/processemail.sh
```

How can I set up so the emails are delivered to the mailbox too and not just eaten by redmine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to read aliases spec? Use it with multi-destination and piped target instead of transport

Comment: Partly. I've changed the above to using transport "local:" and setting the pipe in the aliases file. I still don't know how I can both pipe _and_ deliver the mail. The piping eats the email..

Comment: in aliases you can have `user,|command` in RHS

Comment: But when I have `support: "|cmd"`, the email isn't delivered to the mailbox. It's just send to cmd. I want it to do both - first send to mailbox, then run the command.

Comment: Re-read my RHS - it has **two members**, both used at delivery stage